# Apache not starting after upgrading to a newer version. No errors anywhere

Tags: apache, aix

I had a working configuration of Apache 2.2.23 in an AIX 7 server for around 2 years and I am trying to upgrade it to 2.2.29.
I followed the official documentation to upgrade minor versions by using the ./config.nice file from the old directory and use it to config and install my new apache.
For some unknown reason after it is done when I start apache by ./apachectl -k start it returns nothing (as usual if the config is fine)

However when I do ps -eaf | grep apache nothing is shown, so it didn't run

I then tried ./apachectl -k restart, it says it is not running and the same problem repeats.
Since I backed up the old 2.2.23 folder, if I restore the folder back, it can start immediately.

I then further tested by simply installing 2.2.29 without applying any old configuration to it, so only default configuration is used. Much to my surprise the same problem still persist! Tried rebooting and commenting out LoadModules sentences but nothing works.

No errors on console, just one line of error complaining about SSL cache in error_log (which also happens in the working apache, so I think this error is not related), no errors anywhere...

Grateful if anyone could kindly shed some light on this. Much appreciated, thank you for reading.

Notes:

OS: AIX 7100-02-02

Working Apache: 2-2-23

Tried versions of Apache: 2-2-29 2-2-31

Openssl version: openssl.base 1.0.1.514

EDIT: 
Further testing shows that if I configure the apache with nothing... (only ./configure --prefix=/opt/apache2) then at least it can start.

But when I use my config.nice from my old build which has the following:

"./configure" \

"--prefix=/opt/apache2" \

"--enable-rewrite=shared" \

"--enable-speling=shared" \

"--enable-ssl" \

"--enable-proxy" \

"--enable-proxy-ajp" \

"--enable-proxy-connect" \

"--enable-proxy-ftp" \

"--enable-proxy-http" \

"--enable-vhost-alias" \

"--enable-headers" \

"$@"

it cant start again...